# ASP.NET prevent accessing the homepage before and after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication, session-cookies

I have a login page and a homepage. It's not possible to access homepage without login but after i login and click logout at the homepage. Users are able to access homepage from browser's address row. How can prevent this ? Here is my implementation

Login Click Method at AdminPanelLogin.aspx.cs:

```
protected void adminLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String adminName = adminNameText.Text;
        String password = adminPwdText.Text;

        AdminPanelLoginProcess aplp = new AdminPanelLoginProcess();

        if (aplp.adminLogin(adminName, password))
        {
            Session["AdminAuthentication"] = aplp.Admn.AdminID;
            Response.Redirect("AdminPanel.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Login failed !');</script>");
        }
    }
```

Logout Click Method at AdminPanel.aspx.cs

```
        protected void adminPanelLogoutLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["AdminAuthentication"] = null;
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("AdminPanelLogin.aspx");
    }
```

AdminPanel.aspx.cs Page Load Method:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["AdminAuthentication"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("AdminPanelLogin.aspx");
        }
        else 
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                showProducts();
                showModels();
                showShoes();
            }
            else 
            {
                if (Session["AdminAuthentication"] == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("AdminPanelLogin.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to prevent "Users are able to access homepage from browser's address row."? What is the homepage in this case, is it AdminPanel.aspx?

Comment: What authentication mode are you using?

Comment: The code looks good and should work as expected. Can you please confirm: you have users who could access AdminPanel.aspx without entering login and password? Are these users authorized users (who has login and password, but they just did not enter anything) or these users are not authorized?

Comment: I don't declare any mode in web config. But it is a web forms application.

Comment: @smirnov Without login, there is no access. After a user logins and logs out, i can access adminpanel.aspx via adress ar or browser's back button.

Comment: Even though the back button brings back the cached version of adminpanel.aspx, any action on that side throw the user back to the login page. Whereas the cached page will not call the page_load event, any raised events on adminpanel.aspx will call it and hence fire your authentication checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the back button does not reload the page but get it from cache. Try to disable cache in AdminPanel.aspx as

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
```

or use any other method from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/135121/Browser-back-button-issue-after-logout.aspx

Comment: I have examine that link but i doesn't work for me. And where should i put your codes exactly ?

Comment: You should add it at the begining of Page_Load() method of AdminPanel.aspx. These lines sends to the browser "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store" and "Pragma: no-cache" and prevent caching. So, when user access the page again via address bar or using the back button the browser will not have a cashed version.

Comment: 1) Delete all browser cache and cookies (Tools-Settings-Privacy) and try again. 2) when this does not work and you still get AdminPanel.aspx after being logged out, press Ctrl+F5 to refresh the page, just to see if you will be redirected to AdminPanelLogin or not.

Comment: Still same, nothing change

Comment: If you did 2) and it shows the page, then it looks like session is not deleted. I'd try following. After Session.Abandon(); add Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "")); it will  clear the session ID cookie. After that redirect to Response.Redirect("AdminPanelLogin.aspx?1234567890"); just to be sure that adminPanelLogoutLink_Click() is executed (maybe you have another logout method...)

Comment: Check on AdminPanelLogin.aspx if session is really null e.g. if (Session["AdminAuthentication"] == null) Response.Write("NULL"); else Response.Write("session=" + Session["AdminAuthentication"]);

Comment: I put these codes to onload and after logout the session still contains the id value. But i assigned it to null at logout function. I don't know why it has id value